# How to combine the results of two or more wc commands?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

How to combine the results of two or more wc commands?

```
wc *.foo
wc *.bar
```

To view the sum total for the lines, word count and bytes?

Here is what I have so far:

```
wc *.foo|grep total
wc *.bar|grep total
```

But when I try to combine the commands I get strange behaviour on the command prompt:

```
{ wc *.foo & wc *.bar; }|grep total
```

I would like to pass the output to awk to calculate the sums:

```
awk '{l+=$1; w+=$2; b+=$3} END {print "total lines: " l ", words: " w ", bytes: " b}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wc *.foo *.bar | awk '/total/ {print "total lines: " $1 ,"words: " $2, "bytes: " $3}'
total lines: 18 words: 23 bytes: 53
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `;` to separate commands and enclose them inside a `(` `)`:

```
( wc *.foo ; wc *.bar; ) | grep total
```

Or if you only need wc for that, you can pass both wildcards to it (it will give you the total for both type of files):

```
wc *.foo *.bar | grep total
```